# Option to keep pagination fixed as you are browsing

Tags: feature-request, pagination, preferences

New questions arrive at such a high rate on StackOverflow, that browsing through them in order of most recent to older feels like running on a treadmill - often by the time I go to the next page, most of the questions on there are ones I saw on the previous page.

How about an option (not enabled by default) which for clarity may show a new button like facebook's "Older Entries" button rather than fiddle with the workings of the Prev and Next Page buttons, that shows the next 10 (or 30 or 50 etc) entries older than the last question ID on the page?

I am sure the question ID is indexed in the database so it shouldn't be too inefficient to query it like that.

The option could go on the user preferences page.

Anyway - this is not a critical feature - the site is so close to perfect that this is simply a "I would prefer this nuance" type of request, not a critical piece of missing functionality.

Comment: I understand that it currently works by considering "pages" as a kind of nebulous, always-changing list of the: (# results per page * page offset from newest question).  The problem is I can't imagine a case where that behaviour is actually desirable...to anyone.  I don't think any options should be added.  I think the Next and Prev pages should be "fiddled with" so they submit the last question (ID/timestamp/index/whatever) on each page, so that the next page is relative to that one.